# Hangfire fails after a period of time

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, hangfire

I have setup a hangfire service with a server and a dashboard and I've deployed this to IIS ,
I also created a Db called "HangfireServerDb" and I've started the IIS server. The hangfire server
started and created the require schema and tables and also for a period all jobs ran without any issues.

However at some point I can see in the dashboard this on the job that was scheduled for execution.

> System.InvalidOperationException: Recurring job can't be scheduled, see inner exception for details.
> ---> Hangfire.Common.JobLoadException: Could not load the job. See inner exception for the details.
> ---> System.IO.FileNotFoundException: Could not resolve assembly 'HangfireDashboard.WebApi'.

```
   at System.TypeNameParser.ResolveAssembly(String asmName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Boolean throwOnError, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.ConstructType(Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.TypeNameParser.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError, Boolean ignoreCase, StackCrawlMark& stackMark)
   at System.Type.GetType(String typeName, Func`2 assemblyResolver, Func`4 typeResolver, Boolean throwOnError)
   at Hangfire.Common.TypeHelper.DefaultTypeResolver(String typeName)
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Storage.InvocationData.DeserializeJob()
   at Hangfire.RecurringJobEntity..ctor(String recurringJobId, IDictionary`2 recurringJob, ITimeZoneResolver timeZoneResolver, DateTime now)
   --- End of inner exception stack trace ---
   at Hangfire.Server.RecurringJobScheduler.ScheduleRecurringJob(BackgroundProcessContext context, IStorageConnection connection, String recurringJobId, RecurringJobEntity recurringJob, DateTime now).
```

[image: job failing image]

I need some help in understanding what am I missing or what might the cause be since like I said it works for a period of time thne I'm getting this.

Registration of httpclient

```
services.AddHttpClient<WebPlatformHttpClient>(
                httpClient =>
                {
                    httpClient.BaseAddress = new Uri(_configuration["WebPlatform:Api:BaseUri"]);
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Clear();
                    httpClient.DefaultRequestHeaders.Add(HeaderNames.Accept, "application/json");
                });
```

Httpclient implementation

```
public class WebPlatformHttpClient
{
    private readonly HttpClient _httpClient;
    private readonly IConfiguration _configuration;

    public WebPlatformHttpClient(HttpClient httpClient, IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _httpClient = httpClient;
        _configuration = configuration;
    }

    public async Task SendEmailAsync()
    {
        HttpResponseMessage response = await _httpClient.GetAsync(_configuration["WebPlatform:Api:SendEmail"]);

        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
    }
}
```

Job

```
 RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
            $"Send Email Job",
            "web-platform",
            (WebPlatformHttpClient httpClient) => httpClient.SendEmailAsync(),
            configuration["WebPlatform:Crons:SendEmailCron"], 
            jobOptions);
```

Further investigations

> Application: w3wp.exe CoreCLR Version: 6.0.2623.60508 .NET Version:
> 6.0.26 Description: The process was terminated due to an unhandled exception. Exception Info: System.AggregateException: One or more
> hosted services failed to stop. (A task was canceled.) --->
> System.Threading.Tasks.TaskCanceledException: A task was canceled. at
> Hangfire.Processing.TaskExtensions.WaitOneAsync(WaitHandle waitHandle,
> TimeSpan timeout, CancellationToken token) in
> C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Processing\TaskExtensions.cs:line
> 96 at Hangfire.Processing.BackgroundDispatcher.WaitAsync(TimeSpan
> timeout, CancellationToken cancellationToken) in
> C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Processing\BackgroundDispatcher.cs:line
> 82 at
> Hangfire.Server.BackgroundProcessingServer.WaitForShutdownAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) in
> C:\projects\hangfire-525\src\Hangfire.Core\Server\BackgroundProcessingServer.cs:line
> 148 at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) --- End of inner exception stack trace --- at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.Internal.Host.StopAsync(CancellationToken
> cancellationToken) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.WaitForShutdownAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token) at
> Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting.HostingAbstractionsHostExtensions.RunAsync(IHost
> host, CancellationToken token) at
> HangfireDashboard.WebApi.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> D:\CI_Data\TeamCity\buildAgent2\work\ea4fb37391903d0f\Services\HangfireDashboard\Program.cs:line
> 22 at HangfireDashboard.WebApi.Program.(String[] args)

Comment: Did you rename or changed the HangfireDashboard.WebApi ?

Comment: When you schedule the job, hangfire stores its metadata in the BD. The metadata includes the method that should be executed when time arrives and the type this method is defined on. So, if you make changes to the class or the method the next time Hangfire will fail to execute the job.

Comment: @Artur, there is no change in the deployment  and at some point it just throws the exception I've shared

Comment: @J.Memisevic, no I've not touched, renamed, moved or did anything to the deployment

Comment: Are you sure there are no two jobs in the DB, one is working and one is failing and you think they are the same job?

Comment: @locx I think that AddOrUpdate on existing job should fix your job.

Comment: @J.Memisevic, this is exactly what I'm doing AddOrUpdate ` RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate(
                $"Send Email Job",
                "web-platform",
                (WebPlatformHttpClient httpClient) => httpClient.SendEmailAsync(),
                configuration["WebPlatform:Crons:SendEmailCron"], 
                jobOptions);`

Comment: Can you share your WebPlatformHttpClient in question ? That can be helpfull.

Comment: Do you call your RecurringJob.AddOrUpdate() on startup ? If you do then the restart of application should fix your recuring job. You should just delete that job from dashboard and restart application.